# persistance http calls to external system from wso2 esb

Tags: wso2-esb

How can we restrict http calls from client side(WSO2 esb) to open just one tcp connection with the target server? 
when load increases while calling web service the esb initiate new tcp connection, but i don't want to open the new tcp connections.